# Disallow direct url instead redirect to virtual host url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

How can I restrict direct URL from localhost for example `localhost/abc/aaa.php` should redirect to the virtual host url that ismapped with the above url mentioned i.e. `www.abc.com/aaa.php` and all its sub directory url should respond via the virtual host url.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Every Request to localhost/more/stuff will be redirected to example.com/more/stuff

Comment: I am looking for a particular website that is placed in the localhost folder but not for other folder's